# Matrix into a 4-tensor

Tags: matrices, matlab, tensor-products, tensors

I've been trying to figure out a way to add a dimension to a matrix with a certain rule:

Let our matrix **X** have dimensions **NxM**, **L** be some positive number, and the desired resulting 4-tensor (3d matrix) to be called **R**.

**R** should have dimensions **LxMxN** and be constructed like that: the **LxM** matrix with third axis coordinate **i** should be the **i**-th row of **X** repeated **L** times vertically.

Put shortly, if X*A = R, what is A?

Example:
If X = [[1 2], [3 0], [2 4]] and L = 4

We want the result to be:
    R = 
[[[1 2], [1 2], [1 2], [1 2]], 
         [[3 0], [3 0], [3 0], [3 0]], 
         [[2 4], [2 4], [2 4], [2 4]]]

My final goal is to use it as part of a Matlab program where I should use only preloaded matrix functions and not loops for optimization purposes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you might want to research [hyper](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48045/why-are-matrices-ubiquitous-but-hypermatrices-rare)[matrices](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/work/hla.pdf).

Comment: Questions of the form "how to do this in Matlab" are a better fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: In any case, `reshape(kron(X',ones(L,1)),L,size(X,2),size(X,1))` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you!